# Перенаправление с https на http особую ссылку

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, redirect

Есть ссылка https://mysite.ru/dir/dir2?id=1&name=param_name, необходимо открыть эту ссылку в протоколе http т.е. перенаправить на такую ссылку http://mysite.ru/dir/dir2?id=1&name=param_name

Перепробовал следующие варианты:

## 1 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/dir2$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/dir2$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

- Поменял местами: с начало для перенаправление на https потом http
- Вместо где /dir/dir2$1

  пробовал /dir/dir2(.*) 
  так /dir/dir*, 
  так /dir/dir2.+, 
  так /dir/dir2+?

Результат
https://mysite.ru/dir/dir2?id=1&name=param_name открывает такую же ссылку https://mysite.ru/dir/dir2?id=1&name=param_name

если убрать GET параметры:
https://mysite.ru/dir/dir2 то перенаправляет на index.php, подозреваю, что правила не работает и срабатывает

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

## 2 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule /dir/dir2(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/dir/dir2$1 [R,L]
```

## 2.2 вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule /dir/dir2(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Результат: 
https://mysite.ru/dir/dir2?id=1&name=param_name открывает такую же ссылку https://mysite.ru/dir/dir2?id=1&name=param_name

Подскажите, что не так?

Сервер nginx

Comment: 1. директивы, которые вы привели — это директивы конфигурационного файла программы apache. 2. файл .htaccess, который, вы, вероятно, и правите — это исключительно apache-вский «костыль».

Comment: Для nginx не существует никакого htaccess. Покажите настройки nginx

Comment: @alexanderbarakin - понял. Меня удивляет, почему же тогда в корне лежит .htaccess и его изменения влияет на сайт? Какой то конвертер еще есть, что ли не пойму.

Comment: эти директивы (да и вообще файл .htaccess как таковой) могут влиять **только** на работу программы apache. если влияют, то в формировании ваших веб-страниц участвует **и** эта программа.